# Why is patchcmd not working with moderncv 2.0, but renewcommand is?

Tags: moderncv, patching

I am writing a CV with cover letter using moderncv 2.0 and I would like the line with the recipient to be longer. This question is technically a duplicate of [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/157146/moderncv-cover-letter-recipient-data-line-length), but the given solution does not work for me. When I use

```
\tracingpatches
\patchcmd{\makelettertitle}
  {\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}}
  {\begin{minipage}[t]{.8\textwidth}}
  {}
  {}
```

the output tells me:

```
[debug] tracing \patchcmd on input line 16
[debug] analyzing '\makelettertitle'
[debug] ++ control sequence is defined
[debug] ++ control sequence is a macro
[debug] ++ macro can be retokenized cleanly
[debug] -- search pattern not found in replacement text
```

But when I use renewcommand to rewrite the \makeletterhead command, I can change the size perfectly well. In the MWE I comment out the working part.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[roman]{moderncv}
% Diese drei Pakete benötigen wir für die Umlaute, Deutsche Silbentrennung etc.
\moderncvtheme[black]{classic}         %alternativ: casual

\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\recomputelengths

\tracingpatches

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\makelettertitle}
  {\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}}
  {\begin{minipage}[t]{.8\textwidth}}
  {}
  {}
\makeatother

% \makeatletter
% \renewcommand*{\makeletterhead}{%
%   % recompute lengths (in case we are switching from letter to resume, or vice versa)
%   \recomputeletterlengths%
%   % sender contact info
%   \hfill%
%   \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}%
%     % optional detailed information
%     \if@details%
%       \raggedleft%
%       \addressfont\textcolor{color2}{%
%         {\bfseries\upshape\@firstname~\@lastname}\@firstdetailselementfalse%
%         % optional detailed information
%         \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreet%
%           \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscity}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
%           \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscountry}}%
%         \collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
%           \makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}%
%         \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}%
%         \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\makenewline\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}%
%         \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}}\fi%
%     \end{minipage}\\[1em]
%   % recipient block
%   \begin{minipage}[t]{.8\textwidth}      % original: .5
%     \raggedright%
%     \addressfont%
%     {\bfseries\upshape\@recipientname}\\%
%     \@recipientaddress%
%   \end{minipage}
%   % date
%   \hfill% US style
% %  \\[1em]% UK style
%   \@date\\[2em]% US informal style: "January 1, 1900"; UK formal style: "01/01/1900"
%   % opening
%   \raggedright%
%   \@opening\\[1.5em]%
%   % ensure no extra spacing after \makelettertitle due to a possible blank line
% %  \ignorespacesafterend% not working
%   \hspace{0pt}\par\vspace{-\baselineskip}\vspace{-\parskip}}
% \makeatother

\name{Peter}{Müller}

\title{Lebenslauf}
\address{Hauptstraße 123}{12345 Berlin}
\mobile{0123/45678901}
\email{pink.panther@panthermail.pp}

\nopagenumbers{}                

\begin{document}

%-----       letter       ---------------------------------------------------------
% recipient data
\recipient
  {Super Universität Berlin, FB Superfachbereich und andere Wissenschaften}
  {Institut für Superduper\\
    Angewandte Mathematik und Gender Studies\\
    Frau Prof. Dr. Dr. Prof.\\
    Hauptstr. 456\\
    54321 Berlin}

\opening{Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren,}
\closing{Mit freundlichen Grüßen\newline}
\enclosure[im Anhang]{Lebenslauf, Leistungsübersicht, Immatrikulationsbescheinigung}

\makelettertitle

\end{document}

 % Local variables:
 % mode: latex
 % TeX-open-quote: "\"`"
 % TeX-close-quote: "\"'"
 % TeX-master: t
 % End:
```

I'm not sure whether it is important, but I'm using Emacs.app with AUCTeX on Mac OS X, German language and this is my first question on Stackexchange.

Comment: The message is telling you the reason: "-- search pattern not found in replacement text", so the text that you are searching to replace doesn't match any of the text in the definition.

Comment: I left a comment to the linked answer: I believe that with the current version of `moderncv` one has to patch `\makeletterhead` instead of `\makelettertitle`.

Comment: See this comment by the answerer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/157146/moderncv-cover-letter-recipient-data-line-length#comment629586_157160 I think we can close this question as duplicate, now.